# How can I insert a script inside a Blogger theme?

Tags: javascript, blogger

Maybe I'm a little old, but I think google blogs are the easiest to customize. However, there is a bit of difficulty in inserting files external to the theme. In fact I don't think it can be done. This js file written by an expert I found on the net is to create ia page numbering. I can get it read from his link:

https://gists.rawgit.com/xomisse/ac8ccfa4b8fb2c26d5cf76270db92201/raw/f957494b1691cce3d5a8cb92e5b4ed57cded9729/pagination.js

through the html code:

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/xomisse/ac8ccfa4b8fb2c26d5cf76270db92201/raw/f957494b1691cce3d5a8cb92e5b4ed57cded9729/pagination.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

However, if I try to insert it directly into the theme with or without `//<![CDATA[ at the beginning and //]]> at the end`, it does not work.
I think it is a problem due to the formatting of the code. Probably something like using ' instead of '...Or maybe it's something more complex. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS code given here before </b:skin>

And script before  tag

Source: https://xomisse.com/blog/how-to-add-numbered-pagination-to-blogger/